# Как наложить одну текстуру на другую

Tags: c#, unity3d, текстура

Есть две **Texture2D**, одна из них просто с полоской на прозрачном фоне.
Как их сложить вместе чтоб эта полупрозрачная текстура была сверху на нормальной текстуре?
И еще может быть есть какой то элегантный способ, чтоб не перебирать каждый пиксель?

Comment: Насколько мне изветно объединять текстуры нельзя. Просто создай еще один обхект и положи на него, сделай его по слоям выше и все

Comment: Ладно, я в данный момент разобрал ее по пикселям и методами Бейзера делаю широкие линии от и до вершин развертки
У меня очень много и так объектов и в 2 раза больше очень очень затратно

Comment: 2 материала.....

Comment: С 2мя материалами тоже не очень хорошо выходит, у меня шестиугольник и эти линии это его грани, какие то закрашены какие то нет, 7 материалов на одном шестиугольнике, а их 2500
А потом будет все 7000